# Angularjs in sharepoint 365

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am trying to set a variable from a callback I tried $apply but I got error that $apply is conflicting, after some research I found out that I should use $timeout instead of $apply. So I changed the code as shown below.

```
myApp.controller('dynamicCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {


    var jsonObj = [];

    jsonObj.push({
        "type": "text",
        "model": "text",
        "label": "text",
        "placeholder": "text"
    });

    //$scope.stdFormTemplate = jsonObj;
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('TITLE');
    var listFields = list.get_fields();
    clientContext.load(listFields);

    ctx.load(listFields);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {

        onListFieldsQuerySucceeded(setJsonData);
    },
    function (sender, args) {
        console.log(args);
    });







    function onListFieldsQuerySucceeded(callback) {
        var type = "";
        var fieldEnumerator = listFields.getEnumerator();
        while (fieldEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oField = fieldEnumerator.get_current();
            var fType = oField.get_fieldTypeKind();
            if (fType === SP.FieldType.choice) {

            } else if (fType === SP.FieldType.text) {

            }


        }

        callback(jsonObj);
    }







    function setJsonData(jsonObj) {


        $timeout(function () {
            alert("hithere" +jsonObj);
            $scope.stdFormTemplate = jsonObj;
        }, 0);

    }

    $scope.stdFormData = {};
    $scope.urlFormData = {};
}]);
```

I am trying to achieve this in the function setJsonData, I can see the alert but still  $scope.stdFormTemplate is not getting updated as expected.

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/danhunsaker/angular-dynamic-forms/blob/master/demo/index.html) library.

Comment: take a look at deferred object in Angular or jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using $q and promises.
You can externalize the data access in a factory/service and use promises to handle any async data access operations.

```
myApp.service('spAccess', function($q) {
     this.getListData = function (listName) {
         var deferred = $q.defer();  
         var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
         var list = ctx.get_web().get_listByTitle(listName);
         ctx.load(list);
         ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
            var items = [];
            // Get your data here
            deferred.resolve(items);                
         }, function(err, args){
             deferred.reject([err, args});
         });

         return deferred.promise;
     };
});

myApp.controller('ctrl', function(spAccess, $scope){
    spAccess.getListData('MY LIST').then(function(result){
        $scope.items = result;
    }, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
});

// NOTE: Code was untested, and written on-the-fly, so some minor adjustments/fixes may be neccesary.
```